# PUT: PathVariable and RequestParam don't work together

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, put

I'm using Spring boot 2.1.3-RELEASE. In my RestController I'm trying to set up a PUT method with one PathVariable and a RequestParam (application/x-www-form-urlencoded).
However when I call it the response is a bad request because the required RequestParam is not present.

I tried changing PutMapping to RequestMapping, swapping parameters position and using the syntax @RequestParam(value="param2", required=false) but nothing changes.

Curiously using PostMapping works. Also removing PathVariable works.

Here is the RestController code:

```
@PutMapping(value="/myurl/{param1}", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
public String myMethod( @PathVariable("param1") Integer param1, @RequestParam("param2") String param2);
```

I call the method in this way:

```
curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:8080/myurl/42 \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'param2=myparam2value'
```

The response is:

> {
>       "timestamp": 1553613278534,
>       "status": 400,
>       "error": "Bad Request",
>       "message": "Required String parameter 'param2' is not present",
>       "path": "/myurl/42" 
>   }

I expect that PUT works just like POST, but it seems not to.

Unfortunately I cannot send parameters as QueryParam, so I should maintain the same request call because I am refactoring an existing endpoint that works exactly this way.

Thanks

---

## EDIT

I found this is caused by using an HandlerInterceptorAdapter (via WebMvcConfigurer).
For some reason, around

```
org.springframework.web.util.ContentCachingRequestWrapper.getParameterValues
```

org.apache.coyote.Request.parameters has no content and an exception is thrown, so it works only for POST and not for PUT (GET are handled differently).

I appreciate if someone can suggest if this can be reported as a bug considering that removing the interceptor made it work.

Regards

Comment: http://some.endpoint/api/v1/users/{id}?selector={foo} -- id -> PathParam and 
foo -> RequestParam. My guess is you're conflating "RequestParam" with "body of HTTP request". If your 'param2' is the body of the request, remove the @RequestParam annotation.

Comment: Can you try this : 
curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:8080/myurl/42?param2=myparam2value \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \

Comment: The params come into the request body, not in the param.

Comment: Thank you @Logan Wlv. Unfortunately I need to maintain the same call convention because I am refactoring an existing endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`-G`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-G) along with [`--data-urlencode`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode):

```sh
curl -G -X PUT \
  http://localhost:8080/myurl/42 \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data-urlencode 'param2=myparam2value'
```

From the [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> ### `-G`, `--get`
>
> When used, this option will make all data specified with `-d`, `--data`, `--data-binary` or `--data-urlencode` to be used in an HTTP `GET` request instead of the `POST` request that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a `?` separator. [...]

> ### `--data-urlencode <data>`
>
> (HTTP) This posts data, similar to the other `-d`, `--data` options with the exception that this performs URL-encoding. [...]

Comment: can you explain why his example is working with @PostMapping?

Comment: You need just to read the documentation for -G option: *When used, this option will make all data specified with -d, --data, --data-binary or **--data-urlencode** to be used in an HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. **The data will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator**.*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I am refactoring a legacy endpoint so I cannot change the call. It appears to be a Spring boot bug to me, in my humble opinion.